# When click download button show popup and go to download PDF

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to add popup before going to download pdf in my wordpress site. I try to add contact form 7 event listener but it's not working. Any idea??

```
<p class="margin-xs-top20"><?php 
              if( get_field('download') ): ?>
              <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="file" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-primary btn-huge">download publication
              <script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
            if ( '4265' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends sumissions on form 4265 to the first thank you page
                var pdfLink = '[DOMAIN]/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/file.pdf';
            } else if ( '4266' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends submissions on form 1070 to the second thank you page
                var pdfLink = '[DOMAIN]/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/file2.pdf';
            }
            else {
                //do nothing
            }
            jQuery.get(pdfLink, (data) ->
              window.location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            )
        }, false );
    </script>
</script></button>

                 <?php endif; ?></p>
```

Comment: Not working in what sense? What is happening?

Comment: redirection not working

Comment: "Redirection not working" doesn't help us. Does anything appear on the page? Do you get any errors on screen or in the console? Are the `if` conditions failing and its getting to the `//do nothing` part of your script? We can't help if we don't know whats happening. Try some debugging and let us know the results.

Answer (score 0):

You should have tried to [WP Post Popup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-modal/) WordPress plugin. Maybe you get what you want in your WordPress site